# Edit Quantity Using Javascript price will adjust

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently doing an project on online shopping cart, whereby customers can edit the quantity before checkout. I wanted to make it such that when customer edit the quantity, the price of the item and total price of all items will be adjusted. I know I can achieve that though javascript. Can't really work and understand it. It will be nice if someone would help me. Thank you so so much!
Ps: I am not sure if my codes are correct, but here's what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(form){
    var quantity = document.getElementById('#quantity');
    var price = quantity * ($list['price']);
    document.getElementById("price").value = price;
    ​}
    </script>`
```

I have not done for the total price yet because the price itself isn't working. I know there's something I miss out. Hope someone can enlighten me.

My HTML:

```
`//database query

<td align='middle'><input type="number"  onChange="update(this)"  id="quantity" name="quantity"   min="1" max='<?php echo $list['quantity'] ?>' value='1'></td>

<td><input type="text" id="price" value='<?php echo $list['price'] ?>' readonly></td>

<td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"  readonly></td>`
```

I may have made stupid mistakes,so it will be nice if someone would explain about how javascript works if I got the wrong concepts. Thanks so much for helping!!:)

Comment: For starters, you might want to *not* try to access PHP variables in JavaScript. `var price = quantity * ($list['price']);` isn't going to give you the value of that PHP variable you're echoing below.

Comment: @vch Ah i see..So I have to use document.getElementById? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

see demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDJuqnbmsEwMyTOwcjfb?p=preview)

look this line

```
quantity = document.getElementById('#quantity');
```

in this line remove '**#**'

```
quantity = document.getElementById(**'quantity'**);
```

and use parseint to convert to integer

```
var price = quantity * ($list['price']);
```

$list['price'] is false

to get price you need to do like this:

```
document.getElementById('price').value;
```

final code is :

**form.php**

```
//database query

<td align='middle'><input type="number"  onChange="update(this)"  id="quantity" name="quantity"   min="1" max='<?php echo $list['quantity'] ?>' value='1'></td>

<td><input type="text" id="price" value='<?php echo $list['price'] ?>' readonly></td>

<td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"  readonly></td>`
```

**script.js**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update(form){
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    price = parseInt(price);
    quantity = parseInt(quantity);

    var amount= quantity * price ;

    document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
}


        </script>`
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ruddy Lodonou Oke ! I know more about how javascript works now. However, what if I have more than one item quantity? This only works for 1 item's quantity. Is there any additional codes I need to add in? :)

Answer (score 0):

demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDJuqnbmsEwMyTOwcjfb?p=info)

**index.php**

```
<form> 
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>quantity</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>amount</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <!-- if u use php 
   <?php foreach($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="quantity_$i" name="quantity_$i"   min="1" max='20' value='1'
    onChange="iteration = 1; update(iteration)" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="price_$i" value='25' readonly='readonly' ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount_$i" id="amount_$i"  readonly value='25'></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
   -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" id="quantity_1" name="quantity_1"   min="1" max='20' value='1'
        onChange="iteration = 1; update(iteration)" >
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="price_1" value='25' readonly='readonly' ></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="amount_1" id="amount_1"  readonly value='25'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" id="quantity_2" name="quantity_2"   min="1" max='20' value='1'
        onChange="iteration = 2; update(iteration)" >
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="price_2" value='15' readonly='readonly' ></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="amount_2" id="amount_2"  readonly value='15'></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

**script.js**

function update(iteration){

```
// alert(iteration);

var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + iteration).value;
// alert('quantity_' + iteration);

var price = document.getElementById('price_' + iteration).value;
price = parseInt(price);
quantity = parseInt(quantity);

var amount= quantity * price ;

document.getElementById('amount_' + iteration).value = amount;
```

}